macro to change the color of a cell after i copy it (CTRL+C)
i do a lot of testing and i use a list of barcodes generated in Excel.
I copy the barcode i use, then change the color of the cell so i know which ones are used.
Is there a way a macro could automatically changes the color of the selected cell/s when i copy them using Ctrl + C.
I tried to record a macro and key bind it to Ctrl + C but it come with a Out of Stack Space error.

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+c
'
    Range("E3").Select
    Application.Run "'LPN numbers.xlsx'!Macro2"
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub


i ended up getting it to work using
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+c
'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Copy
End Sub


but now it will happen to any workbooks if i have this one open. how would i restrict it to just this particular workbook?

is your macro calling itself??

The expected behavior of your code is due to its attempt to call itself an infinite number of times (Application.Run). Here is a similar question and a question linked to it. IMO they have nothing to do with your case. Let's tag LPN numbers.xlsx and anything associated with it as source and the 'other one' as target and let's assume you'll try the most upvoted answer to the first linked question...

... If you change your mind about a selected barcode, it's already too late since there is no UnDo to remove the highlights because you have done those using VBA. The same goes if you change your mind after pasting to target or deleting barcodes in target. For these reasons, the whole idea is flawed. You should direct your focus on target i.e. e.g. with the logic "when a barcode is added to target, highlight the matching cell in source"...

... Under certain conditions, this can be achieved in Excel by using Conditional Formatting, or in VBA, by using the Worksheet Change event. Share more detail about source and target (if applicable) i.e. folder path, file (workbook) name (incl. file extension), sheet name, top cell address, screenshots, sample data as text, the required behaviors in various cases,... etc. so we can paint the whole picture and have something to work with or at least suggest what to do.

How do i add LPN numbers.xlsx as the source?

What you need I guess is to record the keys you pressed and to execute the cell fill if the pressed keys were Ctrl+c. To receive this, you can write a macro that watches out if you press this keys and if you do, to execute the fill.
For recognizing the pressed keys, you can use the Windows API function GetAsyncKeyState. This function checks if a specific key is currently pressed or has been pressed since the last call to this function - so exactly what we need. The function returns a number different to zero if a key was pressed. To find out if the keys you look for were pressed you can just check, if the function returns zero or not. You can combine this via an And in an If statement, to check wether both conditions (Ctrl and C) are met. To especially check for Ctrl and C you need to specify this keys, using their Key Code (for Key Codes in general take a look at the Microsoft pages: Keycode constants).
You can pack this into a nice litte loop, so that it will not stop after you pressed Ctrl+C once. Therefore you have to add DoEvents into the loop, what prevents Excel from being stuck in the loop and let's you perform other stuff meanwhile (user interaction in general but also other macros for example). If you don't put it in the loop, you won't even be able to click anywhere within the workbook.
To exit the loop, you can again make use of GetAsyncKeyState and create the loop to stop if you hit the Escape key. Therefore you can use a Do loop, so that it will not stop, until you hit ESC. So put an additional If statement into the loop to check, if Escape was pressed and if so, exit the sub.
The code could look like this:
1. At the top of a Module add the following to make use of the Windows API function (you may have to add a "PtrSafe" after "Declare", but your system will tell you):
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

2. Into the Module write:
    Sub WatchOutForControlC()
   
        Do

            DoEvents        
            If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyC) <> 0 And GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyControl) <> 0 Then Selection.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEscape) <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        Loop

    End Sub

Please pay attention to not press Ctrl+C too quickly and to really push the keys down to the ground, to make sure the macro gets when you are copying!
You could connect this macro to a button or shape on the worksheet, so that you can start it comfortably from the worksheet by clicking on the button or shape without having to open the VBE.
For example: Add a shape to the workbook, right click on it, select "Assign Macro" and select the just created macro from the list, click Ok and afterwards you can call this macro by clicking on the shape.
Let me know if this works.

Or - what I just saw after reading again that you already experimented with binding the macro to shortcuts - take a look at https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/keyboard-shortcut-run-macro/ They describe in detail, how to bind any macro to a shortcut, so you could also use the code you recorded. Just put it in its own "Sub" procedure and erase the "Application.Run" line.
